# D3js tooltip position nxt to cursor

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to position tooltip in d3js next to mouse position. I have found two different way how to do it.

Here [Display tooltip close to the mouse pointer using d3.js in a scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063374/display-tooltip-close-to-the-mouse-pointer-using-d3-js-in-a-scatter-plot)

But it's not working. And also using `d3.select(this).attr("cy")` isn't working.
It seems that position is releated to the chart position also. If it's bottom of page, tooltip is heigher than should be.

What am I missing?

```
on("mouseover", function (d) {
                tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
                .style('left',(d3.event.pageX-180) + 'px')  
                .style("top", d3.select(this).attr("cy") + "px");
}
```

---EDIT--
I think it is also taking scroll position. I mean when chart is at bottom of page and I scroll down to have it on the top of web, it shows me d3.event.pageX = 1648. It's too high value.

[d3.event's x and y coordinates are incorrect while showing tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348061/d3-events-x-and-y-coordinates-are-incorrect-while-showing-tooltip)

But I am using pageX

Comment: Do you use D3 V6?

Comment: Is it a `<g>`, `<rect>`, `<circle>` or something else?

Comment: var rect = svg.selectAll('null')
                .data(data)
                .enter().append('g').append('rect').

Comment: I am using react with  "d3": "^5.7.0",